# How do I make specific inputs go into another .html file in the project?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I wanted to make specific inputs go into another part of a site (e.g. https://myexamplesite.com/anotherpartofit.html)

And also make those specific inputs be the ones that someone saved it in.
An example of what I think would work is: Get value from input 1 from /apartofit.html and put it in input 2 at /anotherpartofit.html and make it non-editable

If it needs to use a database, I would prefer if you could help me with firebase (Google's Database). But in my knowlege, it probably needs to use javascript, so I'll be tagging it, if it doesn't, let me know!

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

in visual studio or notepad or every offline web creating spaces you can't but if you buy a domain or simple , online site , you have to crate a page and get the link of that page then open another page create a button set the button's `href` to link of pervious page finally hit the button !